# How can excitation be used of an alternator to control the power factor?

Tags: power, power-factor-correction, alternator

Looking for ways the excitation of an alternator can control its power factor?

Comment: Power factor is determined by loads

Comment: There is an IEEE std for excitation system representation. In general, the  grid doesn't care about the PF itself. They care about the voltage level, therefore the main goal of the excitation system of the generators is to maintain around 1 pu of voltage at their reference bar.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 In theory, you can design a controller that regulate the PF seen at the output of the generator. OP doesn't mention the application. However, I have doubts this would be useful, only by inspection it seem that such excitation system would be at the margin of stabillity and also the current draws would be ridiculous. In AC, generally you use the inductance of wires, transformers to limit the currents.... Having a controller with a purpose of getting PF=1 would generate extremely high current in the case of a load shedding or a electrical fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The excitation current supplied to a wound-field synchronous generator (WFSG)(alternator) determines the leading or lagging reactive volt-amperes that the generator can supply while operating at a given voltage.

Here are three possible operating conditions:

For a system with just a generator and a load, the excitation is used to maintain the generator voltage at the desired level by matching the reactive volt-ampere requirement of the load. The generator power factor will inherently match the load power factor, but if the load power factor changes, the voltage will change unless the generator excitation is adjusted.

For a system with multiple generators feeding a grid, all generators will inherently operate at the grid voltage and power factor. The excitation of each individual generator can be adjusted to supply a lower or higher share of real power and reactive volt-amperes.  Real power is increased or decreased by increasing or decreasing the driving torque of the prime mover. Reactive volt-amperes is adjusted by adjusting the generator excitation.

A WFSG can also be operated as a capacitor to increase the power factor of a load that has a lagging power factor. In that case, the WFSG supplies only reactive volt-amperes while real power is supplied by the grid through one or more other generators.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the field current (excitation) increases the synchronous machine voltage behind the reactance. This increases the var (Q) flow out of the machine.  Increasing the mechanical power into the machine (shaft torque, assuming generator) will increase the power flow (P) out of the machine.

Answer (score 0):

> How can excitation be used of an alternator to control the power factor?

Power factor is determined by load, **and is not possible by the source for a single alternator.**  Reactive load currents increase supply conduction losses that do not generate work at the load.

On a grid that could be done by phase control of an alternator as PFC at expense of energy to generate this correction.

Power factor is the ratio of real work energy to total energy and the difference is reactive or stored energy necessary for motors (lagging current) and charging capacitors (pulsed = distorted leading current)